# Change AVPlayerViewController background to album artwork objective-c iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

Is it possible to change the background of an AVPlayerViewController instance when playing audio ?

When I lock my device, I can see the music controls with album artwork correctly shown but when the AVPlayerViewController is shown in my app, I can only see the controls with a background representing QuickTime currently playing.

Here is how I call it :

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];


        NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:clickedPath];
        AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];


        AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
        controller.player = player;
        [player play];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can customize `AVPlayerViewController` by customizing it's `contentOverlayView`.

You can customise `contentOverlayView`.

see the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayerViewController/contentOverlayView), it states

> You can use the content overlay view to add additional custom views between the video content and the playback controls.

for example,

```
  AVPlayerViewController *controller =  [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];

[controller.contentOverlayView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

like wise you can add other controls like button,label etc to that `contentOverlayView`.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I think this would be the correct way to do it ! However when I try to show a view created programmatically with contentOverlayView, nothing happen (Or even If I copy your setBackgroundColor part)

Comment: Ignore my last comment, I've managed to get an UIImageView showing as an overlay. I last need to get the album artwork ! Thanks for your help :)