# Set background image of AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

i'm using AVPlayerViewController for playing audios. Reason for using it is that it provides and handles basic controls i.e. play/pause/slider/volume.

Now, i need to set background image of this view. Image will be fetched from some network location. i debugged AVPlayerViewController's view hierarchy. There's an image view. I'm not sure how to access that or even if it's possible

I don't want to use AVPlayer or AVAudio player as in that case i'll have to handle all the controls.How can i do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you can customize AVPlayerViewController by customizing it's contentOverlayView.

Add UIImageView as contentOverlayView.Add button etc also if you want custom design for them too.

```
controller.contentOverlayView.addsubview(myImageView)
```

To cahnge color etc:

```
controller.contentOverlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 178/255, green: 178/255, blue: 122/255, alpha: 1)
```

for more check following link

[Change AVPlayerViewController background to album artwork objective-c iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298000/change-avplayerviewcontroller-background-to-album-artwork-objective-c-ios)

Comment: Question is tagged with Swift, not objective-c

Comment: Thanks much. You saved my day :)

Comment: the video does not play or show once I do this.